# Best way to manage multiple Google Sheets in BQ and then to Power BI

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, powerbi, data-warehouse, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to warehouse data from Google Sheets in BQ. Basically, we have about 20 different spreadsheets that all have the same tab 'RMLData' that cleans and organizes data. The 'RMLData' tab is identical across all spreadsheets.

[RMLData tab preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWZkB.png)

In BQ, I want to add each 'RMLData' tab from each individual spreadsheet as a data source and have BQ combine the data from all 'RMLData' tabs into one big table that refreshes every hour.

Then, I need PowerBI to be able to receive the data from BQ and have that be auto-refreshed as well.

Question: what would be the best approach here to combine data from about 20 different Google Sheets in BQ that auto-refreshes at least once an hour?

Note: I have successfully appended queries of all the 'RMLData' tabs in Power BI but I'm **not** sure that's a **scalable option** as the company continues to grow bigger.

I think my best bet, in order to setup a framework that can handle even larger amounts of data, is to gather and organize the data from all 'RMLData' tabs in BQ and have that be able to be sourced to Power BI and/or some other BI software (Tableau, Data Studio, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this if you want to retain the google sheet files is to take advantage of the external tables feature in BigQuery.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive

By creating external tables, you are preserving the source data as it is (google sheets) and leveraging BigQuery as the query engine, without having to ingest the data into BigQuery and therefore have a system in place to refresh it.

The SQL queries on top of those external tables will always pull fresh data, so PowerBI or others can also benefit from that.

Please, be aware of the limitations of this solution, especially in terms of performance.

If performance is an issue, then you must consider an alternative solution and ingest the data into BigQuery.

Comment: David - thank you!

How would I ingest the data into BigQuery?

Comment: External tables do not need any ingestion at all. If you are considering ingestion and not use external tables, there are a few options.

1. dataflow and cloud scheduler
2. data fusion (if you prefer a low-code solution)
3. INSERT INTO plus SELECT using external tables + Scheduled queries.

In scenario 3 you use external tables as a way to retrieve data using a SQL query and INSERT that data directly into a bigquery dataset.

You can schedule a query to refresh that data (truncate, insert)